# Make a subscription in a Queue Manager

Tags: docker, queue, containers, websphere, message-queue

***Be sure that you must have Docker and IBM MQ installed before answering this question***

I'm studying and trying to understand the IBM Websphere MQ tool since a while, and my goal here is pretty much a "simple one", make a subscribe to a Queue.

I'm trying to make this through some weak & confusing tutorials that i've ended up finding, and now i'm stuck at this.

I used this link to access IBM MQ console, most for setting up Queues, Topics, Subscriptions and stuff: https://hub.docker.com/_/ibm-mq-advanced
Once you proceed to checkout, download the "script" that settles up the container and pull the image (both are at this link). With this step done, i started the container and entered in: 
https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/console/ to be able to interact w/ the console. The user is "admin", with "passw0rd" as its login data.

You'll most likely see a screen like this:
[image: screenshot]
Now, i need to implement this with Node.JS, so I picked the following project:

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs

Well, after all this, i just added a message to a queue, by simply going to the Queues widget and putting a message through the icon. After this, i honestly feel lost, i don't know how can i publish into a queue and then let it available for subscription (there's a subscription widget that you can add).

You guys will see that into the git project, there's plenty of samples available, but i don't know how to use the amqspub and amqssub properly, i really need some help, idk how to "connect" the topics from 2 messages and make a sub.

Making a proper topic setup is key for subscription, so i need this too.

I really don't know if you, that are reading this ,got my problem rightand will be able to help with that git project...

Comment: Hello. This seems like quite complicated general question. Could you provide some code, where you stuck? Have you checked the [issues list](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/issues?utf8=✓&q=is%3Aissue+) of that git? Could you contact IBM's developers directly for help?

Comment: Queue, Topics, Subscriptions, Channels are all objects under a queue manager in IBM MQ. The concepts are well explained in the following link : 
  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v91.doc/WelcomePagev9r1.htm

Specifically regarding publisher and subscriber is explained in the below link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q004870_.htm